# How to show the data based on current logged in user in MVC 4?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, authentication

I have login authentication based asp.net MVC 4 application with Entity Framework. Here, user can get registered themselves and add their own records in the application.

So, Whenever they are logging in, they should just see their own records and not others. Would like to filter the records based on current logged user.

Is there any simple approach that we can do it without affecting the performance? Is it possible to do it one place to handle this scenario?

User   Id    Value

1      1      Test value of 1
2      2      Test value of 2
2      3      Test value of 3
1      4      xyzabc

Also, Need to restrict the user 2 by viewing the by url hits
Ex :
http://wesite.com/Details/1 and http://wesite.com/Details/4 should not be viewed by user 2 and vice-versa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try creating a ApplicationUser class that inherits from IdentityUser with any custom properties you want to add to that user:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{      
    public int CustomProperty { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Then you pass the ApplicationUser to the dbcontext:

```
public class YourDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
```

And when you want to get data for a specific user just get the Identity of the logged on user:

```
var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();

_dbContext.YourTable.Where(x => x.UserId = userId);
```

This way you don't have to restrict your routes for specific ids, just use the Id of the current logged on user to get the data you need.

Comment: I'm currently getting it thru User.Identity.GetUserId(). but is there any way to implement that user authorization at one place and show the data? In your case, I have to duplicate the _dbContext.YourTable.Where(x => x.UserId = userId);  for all other methods in the controllers also to other controllers methods. Please let me know if we have generic approach that can be accessible by other controllers too.

Comment: You can create a base Controller class where you can set a property UserId and set it with User.Identity.GetUserId(); so it will be accessible to all controllers inheriting from it. _dbContext.YourTable.Where(x => x.UserId = userId); will depend on what data you want to get in each action and each controller.

Comment: Thank you so much  Alan. It is working across all controllers. as I mentioned in my example, is there a approach to handle the authorization at one place rather checking the above condition (your solution) in all other places? for simple projects, this will work fine. but assume, if we have 10 to 20 modules, implementation of this would be difficult right?