# How to ensure that a logged in employee can only view his sales record but Admin can view all?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm learning asp.net, I have created simple web application for storing sales record using a form, employee record, I'm wondering how I can make sure no employee can view sales data of any other employee and make changes to them but Admin or employee manager can view all of their records?

using a simple Model for now:

```
{
public ApplicationUser Employee{ get; set; }
public int EmpId { get; set; }
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Po { get; set; }
public long So { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Your records already contain a property for `ApplicationUser`, so you just need to get only records for the current user (or if the user has `Admin` permissions, get all records)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Entity Framework queries to only get the sales records of the currently logged in employee. If the user is in an Admin role, then you will query for all of the sales records.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31624125/how-to-show-the-data-based-on-current-logged-in-user-in-mvc-4) question may provide more assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the role of user and based on that you query the result
here see sample code:

```
           var TheUser = db.MyUsersContext.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName.Equals(TrimedUser, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
        if (TheUser != null)
        {
            var TheRoles =
                 from r in db.MyRoleContext
                 where TheUser.RoleId == r.Id
                 select r.RoleName;
            if (TheRoles != null)
            {
                return TheRoles.ToArray();
            }
            else
            {
                return new string[] { };
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return new string[] { "Viewer" };
        }
```

and based on return values you can query database